# How can I calculate difference between number value and current time in SQL?

Tags: oracle

I have old design number datatype column used to save arrival time and I converted the values in the
column to be like time format using this query :

```
    SELECT (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(arrival_TIME),4,'0'),'HH24MI'),'HH24:MI')) AS "Arrival time" , 
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI')) -
    TO_NUMBER((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(arrival_TIME),4,'0'),'HH24MI'),'HH24:MI'))) 
     AS "Length of Stay" 
    FROM EMR_FILES 
    WHERE emr_no =00299;
```

when I run the query I got error

```
ora-01722 invalid number
```

how to correct the query and get the difference between arrival time and current time ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI'))` converts, say, `TIMESTAMP '2023-08-28 23:20:00'` first to the string `'23:20'` which you then want to convert to a number. `'23:20'` though, is not a number.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes you are right I removed TO_NUMBER and : and its working thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the time difference as an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type, you can use:

```sql
SELECT LPAD(arrival_TIME,4,'0') AS "Arrival time" , 
       ( TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MI')
         - TO_DATE(
             TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') || LPAD(arrival_TIME,4,'0'),
             'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'
           )
       ) DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) AS "Length of Stay" 
FROM   EMR_FILES 
WHERE  emr_no =00299;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emr_files (emr_no, arrival_time) AS
SELECT 299,    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 299, 2359 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| Arrival time | Length of Stay |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | +0 21:27:00 |
| 2359 | -0 02:32:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ilgh3sd4)

Comment: thank you I got the idea and solved it its working :)

Answer (score -1):

I got the idea from MTO and solved it by removing TO_NUMBER AND ':'

like this

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MI') - (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(arrival_TIME),4,'0'),'HH24MI'),'HH24MI')) AS "ELOS"
```

thank you for your time

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense. You are subtracting one string from another? Oracle converts these two strings into numbers implicitly in order to do the math.  (It should better raise an error in my opinion.) And with 3:59 to 4:00 you get 0400 - 0359 = 41. What is this result supposed to mean?

Comment: the result will be how many minutes waiting time from arrival time till now , after that I will collect statistics to see all waiting times , I will check also the other solutions thank you

Comment: No, the result won't be the number of minutes, as already shown. From 3:59 to 4:00 there is just one minute, but 400 - 359 make 41. Your solution is wrong. If you want minutes, calculate (to_hours * 60 + to_minutes) - (from_hours * 60 + from_minutes).

Comment: And all this only works for the same day, of course. If you have an arrival time 23:30 and look at the duration at 1 am, you'll get a negative result, unless you have stored the arrival day, too, and use it in the calculation.

Comment: Yes I will work on this if different days need calculations also